# unable to access Photo library on iOS 10.3.1, Xcode 7

Tags: cordova, ios10

My app using cordova and xcode7 for the build.

I need to enable users to access photo library to use their photos as profile picture. It works fine on iOS 10.2 and older version, but on iOS 10.3, I can't find any photo library privacy on the settings anymore, also when I trying to access the photo library, it opens camera directly other than give you options to select take a pic or choose from your album.

I found that may be related to new privacy feature brought by iOS 10. `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`, I added this value on Xcode7 but didn't work for me.

Do I need to ask permission programmatically?

Comment: Are you using the camera plugin or HTML elements to try and open the photo library?

Comment: I am using HTML elements like: `<input type="file" id="xx" accept="image/*" capture="camera" required>`. after I removed `capture="camera"`, the code works on iOS